# creating virtual interface for remote network interface

Tags: networking

I have to create virtual interface for control plane algorithms for layer 2 protocol algos.....
Scenarios is somewhat like this....
Control plane will be executing on Centralised card executing Control Plane logic.....
Data plane will be part of line cards executing fast path switching and routing.......
My requirement is I have to create virtual interfaces at Control plane which should map to actual interface on Line cards.

Can I use TAP for this..........??

Comment: You should really try to explain yourself more clearly and invest some time to make a understandable question.

Answer (score 0):

It will help if you can provide more information but since the tag is networking and you're talking about TAP I'll do my best to answer from what I understand it might be.

If this is pure networking, then a simple ifconfig eth0:1 plumb will activate the virtual network interface and then you can just configure it using the normal procedures for most of the *nix.

Now, to make that kind of matching, I guess you will need to perform static routes. 
You will need to use route and specify that the source ip/interface to match the desired interface on the destination.